# Configure Caching IPv4/IPv6 DNS Stub Resolver using "systemd-resolved"

Tags: raspbian, networking, dns, systemd, cache

"***How Do I configure a local caching DNS stub Resolver using "systemd-resolved"?***"

I've been using ***BIND*** to enhance performance by caching name queries on hosts.  Since ***systemd-resolved*** is part of the systemd furniture, I decided to adopt it in lieu of using ***BIND***.

However, what should have been trivial to configure turned into an exercise in confusion: not much on ***systemd-resolved*** on the 'net and what I found ***varied materially by both systemd version and OS***. There's `man systemd-resolved`, but this alone won't get you across the finish line.

I document in the answer below how I arrived at a correctly working IPv4/IPv6 ***systemd-resolved*** DNS caching stub resolver on Raspbian so hopefully others will avoid wasted time, effort & grief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, identify the version of ***systemd*** on your system. This is crucial to understanding the validity of ***systemd-resolved*** links you're reading on the 'net:

```
systemctl --version
```

In respect to ***systemd-resolved***, systemd ***v239*** has some material changes. If you see "***resolvectl***" being mentioned, the document you're reading relates to ***systemd-resolved*** as ships with systemd ***v239*** or later. At the time of this writing Raspbian is using ***v232***

No need to install ***systemd-resolved*** on Raspbian- it's already there.
HOWEVER: you **MUST** install `libnss-resolve`. It although systemd-resolved is installed, this dependency is **NOT**:

```
apt-get install libnss-resolve
```

Let's find the files we have to work with:

```
locate resolved
```

Note: ***locate*** command requires ***mlocate*** to be installed.

*systemd-resolved* 's own ***resolv.conf*** can't be read directly but must be exposed as a symlink to ***/etc/resolv.conf***

```
rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

***/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf*** is populated with the DNS resolvers specified in ***/etc/systemd/resolved.conf***.  Mine looks as follows:

***/etc/systemd/resolved.conf*** :

```
[Resolve]
DNS=192.168.3.126 8.8.8.8 2001:4860:4860::8888
FallbackDNS=8.8.4.4 2001:4860:4860::8844
#Domains
LLMNR=yes
DNSSEC=no
Cache=yes
DNSStubListener=udp
DNSOverTLS=opportunistic
```

You'll note the first resolver is an ***RFC1918*** non-world-routable IP: ***why use this?!?!***  Because that's my Pi's router GW connection which has been set to cache DNS queries.  So the Pi will try to resolve from the router's cache first and if the query cannot be answered there, ***systemd-resolveed*** will reach out across the 'net to a distant DNS server.

So as soon as any host in the subnet resolves a name now, all the Pi's can grab that mapping from the router and it will be cached locally making everything a bit snappier.

Even if the router is rebooted and its' DNS cache is consequently blown-away, the Pi's will retain their DNS caches.  Sweet.

***/etc/nsswitch.conf***:
Add "***resolve***" to the front of the list so name resolution is attempted by the stub resolver first:

```
hosts:          resolve dns files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]
```

***/etc/dhcpcd.conf***: In order to bypass DHCP assigning our DNS servers, we need to tweak this file by removing `domain_name_servers` to look as below:

```
#option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option domain_name, domain_search, host_name
```

Finally, we need to read the changes we just made to ***/etc/systemd/resolved.conf***:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

If you look at ***/etc/resolv.conf*** now, you'll see the DNS servers you specified.

If your config is righteous, should see a status as below:

```
sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.d
           └─resolvconf.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-04-24 16:27:10 BST; 9min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
  Process: 17635 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /run/resolvconf/enable-updates ] || echo "nameserver 127.0.0.53" | /sbin/resolvconf -a systemd-resolved (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 17634 (systemd-resolve)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
           └─17634 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
```

Lets run some tests:

```
ping -c1 www.google.com
ping6 -c1 www.google.com
```

Yes, those ping by name.

Let's resolve directly against the ***systemd-resolved*** local caching stub resolver next:

```
systemd-resolve www.microsoft.com 127.0.0.1
systemd-resolve www.microsoft.co.uk 127.0.0.1
```

NOTE: `systemd-resolve` is ***pre-*** ***systemd v239***.  Use `resolvectl query` instead if ***systemd version*** is ***v239*** or later

Results will look as follows:

```
pi@pi3Bplus-tablet:~ $ systemd-resolve www.microsoft.com 127.0.0.1
www.microsoft.com: 2a02:26f0:ec:39d::356e
                   2a02:26f0:ec:395::356e
                   84.53.169.145
                   (e13678.dspb.akamaiedge.net)
-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 55.6ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
127.0.0.1: pi3Bplus-tablet
           pi3Bplus-tablet.f1linux.com

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 3.9ms.
-- Data is authenticated: yes
```

Now let's look at our cache statistics:

```
pi@pi3Bplus-tablet:~ $ systemd-resolve --statistics
DNSSEC supported by current servers: no
Transactions
Current Transactions: 0
  Total Transactions: 14
Cache
  Current Cache Size: 6
          Cache Hits: 7
        Cache Misses: 7
DNSSEC Verdicts
              Secure: 0
            Insecure: 0
               Bogus: 0
       Indeterminate: 0
```

Another useful command is:

```
systemd-resolve --status
```

**NOTE:** Any time you either reboot or `systemctl restart systemd-resolved` you'll blow-away the cache which lives in memory.  Obviously cold caches are non-performant, so avoid doing this if possible.

Can't over-emphasize the importance of employing caching of DNS queries on a local stub resolver.  This will have a material impact on performance.

I think I've covered it all.  If you spot any errors or omissions please ping me and I'll make the appropriate updates. HTH folks- T